# Loading JavaScript files - conditional concatenation

Tags: javascript, conditional-comments

To reduce http requests, I'm using grunt to combine all of my scripts into 2 files: scripts-head.js and scripts-body.js.

There are some scripts (shims, for example) that only need to be served to legacy IE browsers. So should I:

1. Use a conditional comment like `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` - but this will now mean more http requests.
2. Just add the legacy IE scripts along with the other concatenated files - this will result in extra unused code for modern browsers, but will mean less http requests.
3. Another option?? (some way to do conditional concatenation?)

Comment: Which is the larger bottleneck? More requests may not be bad if the scripts are being cached and only requested from the server once. On the other hand, if the combined scripts are compressed before being sent, the size difference "over the wire" may not be significantly larger.

Comment: How much "legacy code" do you have?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a conditional comment. It is cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general consensus right now is that instead of worrying about browser version (you can't keep track of them all), people use feature detection with library like Modernizr and load polyfills for missing features.

Modernizr itself comes with an async loader that allows you to specify loading polyfill script based on the truthiness of feature testing (read: only issue extra request for polyfills if necessary).

In any strategy, don't worry about that one extra HTTP request because once the browser caches the file, there won't be any request.